# Showing radiobuttons when dropdown item selected

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new to Javascript language and I am dealing with the following:

When the visitor clicks on any item within a dropdownlist, four radiobuttons
must be seen.

This is the html code of the dropdown list:

```
<div class="xmp-form-row ">
    <Label CssClass="xmp-form-label" For="wijzigingOpvangVestiging">Vestiging waar uw kind geplaatst is</Label>
    <DropDownList Id="wijzigingOpvangVestiging" DataField="wijzigingOpvangVestiging" DataSourceId="dsLocaties" DataTextField="Vestiging" DataValueField="Vestiging" DataType="string" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
        <ListItem Value="niet geselecteerd">(Selecteer een vestiging)</ListItem>
    </DropDownList>
</div>
```

And this is the code of the radiobuttons:

```
<div class="xmp-form-row radioButtonCheckfirst locationRB">
    <Label CssClass="xmp-form-label" For="wijzigingReden">Reden beeindiging</Label>            
    <radiobuttonlist id="wijzigingReden" datafield="wijzigingReden" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" datatype="string">
        <listitem value="Uitbreiding van dagen-uren"> Uitbreiding van dagen/uren </listitem>
        <listitem value="Gedeeltelijke opzegging"> Gedeeltelijke opzegging </listitem>
        <listitem value="Wijziging van vestiging"> Wijziging van vestiging </listitem>
        <listitem value="Wijziging van dagen"> Wijziging van dagen </listitem>
    </radiobuttonlist>                                    
</div>
```

Comment: What's you question? What's the problem occurring at the moment?

Comment: If one of our answers was helpful please set it as your solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
    <DropDownList onchange="document.getElementById('wijzigingReden').style.display = ''" Id="wijzigingOpvangVestiging" DataField="wijzigingOpvangVestiging" DataSourceId="dsLocaties" DataTextField="Vestiging" DataValueField="Vestiging" DataType="string" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
        <ListItem Value="niet geselecteerd">(Selecteer een vestiging)</ListItem>
    </DropDownList>
```

and set the radio buttons to be display none on page load.

```
    <radiobuttonlist style="display: none" id="wijzigingReden" datafield="wijzigingReden" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" datatype="string">
        <listitem value="Uitbreiding van dagen-uren"> Uitbreiding van dagen/uren </listitem>
        <listitem value="Gedeeltelijke opzegging"> Gedeeltelijke opzegging </listitem>
        <listitem value="Wijziging van vestiging"> Wijziging van vestiging </listitem>
        <listitem value="Wijziging van dagen"> Wijziging van dagen </listitem>
    </radiobuttonlist>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Andrew thanks for you efford. The thing is, i get the next message in console (firebug): showDiv is not defined.

Comment: My code doesn't use the showDiv function.  My example just uses the inline code...      onchange="document.getElementById('wijzigingReden').style.display = ''"

Comment: Here's an example on jsfiddle. another part of your problem is your drop down list only has one item so you can't actually execute onchange.  http://jsfiddle.net/crazidiamond/srLB3/3/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to bind `change` event to your Dropdown. [docs](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="dropDownDiv" class="xmp-form-row " onChange="showDiv()">
        <Label CssClass="xmp-form-label" For="wijzigingOpvangVestiging">Vestiging waar uw kind geplaatst is</Label>
        <DropDownList Id="wijzigingOpvangVestiging" DataField="wijzigingOpvangVestiging" DataSourceId="dsLocaties" DataTextField="Vestiging" DataValueField="Vestiging" DataType="string" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            <ListItem Value="niet geselecteerd">(Selecteer een vestiging)</ListItem>
        </DropDownList>
    </div>

<radiobuttonlist  id="wijzigingReden" datafield="wijzigingReden" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" datatype="string" style="display: none">
        <listitem value="Uitbreiding van dagen-uren"> Uitbreiding van dagen/uren </listitem>
        <listitem value="Gedeeltelijke opzegging"> Gedeeltelijke opzegging </listitem>
        <listitem value="Wijziging van vestiging"> Wijziging van vestiging </listitem>
        <listitem value="Wijziging van dagen"> Wijziging van dagen </listitem>
    </radiobuttonlist> 

<script type="text/javascript">
   function showDiv(){
       if( document.getElementById('wijzigingReden').style.display == "block"){
          document.getElementById('wijzigingReden').style.display = "none";
       }
       else{
          document.getElementById('wijzigingReden').style.display = "block";
       }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanls for the information guys! But is there a way to do this only on a non-native way. So only with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Add a css class "hidden" to the radiobutton enclosing div that hides the buttons/label initially, then using jquery...

```
$("#wijzigingOpvangVestiging").change(function() {
    $("#nameoftheradiobuttondiv").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Fiddle here... http://jsfiddle.net/Z5nNW/2/